# Android not use DNS personal! (Spoofing ipv6 DNS possible?)

Tags: networking, security, wifi, dns, android

I have a personal **DNS server** (use **ubound**) in my network. I disabled my home wifi router's DNS to use my own and pass my personal router's DNS parameters for **ads blocking**. All home devices work properly except android smartphones!! I've tried everything! I disabled **Private DNS**, both in android settings and in chrome. I set the firewall to block forwarding of packets on ports **53**, **853** and also **5353** (for security) in order to force the use of my dns...but nothing! It does not work! As a last test I set the android wifi DNS **MANUALLY** and it doesn't even work! How is it possible? And above all ... how can it be solved? Thank you

**UPDATE**:
I disabled my home router's DHCP in favor of my server's. However I have noticed one thing. I tried turning off my DNS/DHCP server and connected a device. I repeat, the home router has DHCP disabled, but when I try to connect and see in the network settings, I find the DNS1 entry with the ipv6 of the home router!!! Unfortunately I can't disable DHCPV6 from the router. Is there some way (even with Packet **Spoof**) to trick the devices into giving them my dns (ipv6 in this case) instead of the router's?
Evidently, android gives precedence to ipv6 instead of ipv4. I can't find any other explanation....

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, this only works with Private DNS and setting Private DNS provider hostname, assuming ubound supports DNS-over-HTTPS (DOH), otherwise it will fall back to Google's DNS servers.

Comment: By any chance, does Android give precedence to ipv6 instead of ipv4?

Comment: As far as I know Android doesn't give IPv6 preference over IPv4. Disabling DHCP won't fix the auto-resolving of your DNS server, since that's embedded in Android itself, So changing the DNS on your router is a good idea, but doesn't affect your Android device, I know stupid.
I think only aforementioned DOH works or a VPN client like https://1.1.1.1. Alternatively you could setup your own OpenVPN server. Or switching to an alternative like GrapheneOS, but I'm no expert on that.

Comment: @royarisse I think it is not so, and I will also explain why.  As gateway I set my router and I set some firewall rules that block packet forwarding on port 53,853,5353... so, if it's like you say, the dns (albeit DoH) shouldn't work.  Yesterday I did another test, both on win7 and win10.  For both, I had ipv6 disabled on the interfaces.  everything works as expected.  But if I try to enable ipv6 too, my dns doesn't work anymore!  in fact if I try to check in the settings I notice that the ipv6 settings are those of the home router and in the ipv6 settings they are before the ipv4.  So, how ca

Comment: So, how can you solve this problem yourself?  I don't know where to hit my head anymore.